# what is the difference between .o and .os objs in glibc

Tags: compilation, glibc

I am studying the source code of glibc. I found when compiling glibc I get some .o objs and some .os objs. E.g., there is a dl-load.o, as well as a dl-load.os. So, what is the difference between them?

Thank you!
Yiming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SETUP: glibc2.3.4

**EXPERIMENT**

First, nm on `glibc/bld/close.{o,os}` shows that only `close.o` has `syscall_error` defined.
Then, write a simple program to detect whether `syscall_error` is used in `close()`.

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() { 
    return close(fileno(stdin));
}

gcc -o s.out -static -g a.c
gcc -o d.out -g a.c
```

**RESULT**

`gdb` shows that only `close()` in `s.out` make use of `syscall_error`. Thus .o file is for `static library` while .os is for `dynamic library`.